# How do I know if a library is server-side or client-side library?

Tags: client-server, server-side, client-side, terminate

Correct me if I am wrong, a server side library runs on a server, and a client side library runs on the user's computer.

However, how do I know if a library runs on server or client? Is there a rule of thumb?

For example, why are node.js libraries server side libraries if you install it on your local machine and run it on your local machine?

If the library is executed somewhere locally but outside of a browser, is it still considered a client side library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you read these two articles. They should give you some clarity on Node.js functionality and server and client side scripting.

Server VS Client
https://skillcrush.com/2012/07/30/client-side-vs-server-side/

Intro to Node.js
https://www.google.com/amp/s/opensourceforu.com/2016/01/an-introduction-to-node-js-the-server-side-javascript/amp/